# How to use ActionFilterAttribute to log running times?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I created an action filter for measuring running times of every action in an Web API v2.

```
public class RunningTimeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly ILogFactory _logFactory;
        private readonly ITimerFactory _timerFactory;
        private ITimer _timer;
        private ILogger _logger;

        public RunningTimeAttribute(ILogFactory logFactory, ITimerFactory timerFactory) {
            if(logFactory == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("logFactory");
            if(timerFactory == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("timerFactory");

            _logFactory = logFactory;
            _timerFactory = timerFactory;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
            OnBeforeAction(actionContext);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) {
            OnAfterAction(actionExecutedContext);
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        }

        private void OnBeforeAction(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
            var controllerName = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller.GetType().FullName;
            var actionName = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

            _logger = _logFactory.Create(controllerName);
            _logger.Trace("Action \"{0}\" begins execution", actionName);

            _timer = _timerFactory.Create();
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void OnAfterAction(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) {
            var actionName = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

            _timer.Stop();
            _logger.Trace("Time elapsed for action \"{0}\": {1} msec", actionName, _timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

}
```

However, action filters act as singletons, so when `OnActionExecuted` runs, I cannot be sure that the `_logger` and `_timer` correspond to the ones created for the *same action `OnActionExecuting`*.

Eg.

1. Action Foo1 begins execution. `_logger = "logger1"`, `_timer = "timer1"`.
2. Action Foo2 begins execution. `_logger = "logger2"`, `_timer = "timer2"` (they get overriden)
3. Action Foo1 ends execution. It stops timer and logs elapsed time which is nonsense (end1-start2).

**Question**: Is there a way I can know in `OnActionExecuted` to which `OnActionExecuting` it corresponds? If there was some unique identifier for actions, I could use it as a key to a Dictionary to store any action-related objects such as loggers and timers. Is there any? Or some other solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as Web API is concerned the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is not always guaranteed. It depends on whether you are using Web API Self hosted or not. That is the main reason that when overriding `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting` you don't get an httpcontext property on the `HttpActionContext` parameter (In AspNet MVC you do).

The best way to do the same is the `actionContext.Request.Properties` dictionary.

check also this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14921062/61577)

Answer (score 2):

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items is a per-request cache store.
You can safely add the timer object in Items in OnBeforeAction method and retrieve this timer object from Items in OnAfterAction method